# Determining which Function Graph grows faster

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to determine which function grows faster with the following functions.

> Red = $f(n)=3^n$ and Blue = $g(n)=3^{n+1}$

This is a pretty easy graph to draw, but wasn't sure if growing faster meant the rapidness in slope increase or just being infront?

[image]

Comment: $g(n)/f(n)=3$,  a constant .Hence they grow at the same rate. But if you talk about slope at a particular point, $g$ has a greater slope.

Comment: It depends on the definition of "growing faster". The fraction tends to a constant, but the difference tends to $\infty$. If we do not deal with computational complexities (where constants play no role), I would consider $g(x)$ to grow faster than $f(x)$.